# Problem with remoted display of java applications

Tags: windows, linux, java, xorg, xming

I'm trying to remote display Java based development environments, such as NetBeans and IntelliJ, from a linux machine to a windows machine.  When I do this, the right click functionality of the environments does not work, which makes them unusable.

I use the -X option with Putty to tunnel X through SSH.  I've repeated this using Ubuntu and RedHat to my Windows running Xming.   Is there a trick to remote Xing java applications that I'm missing?

Comment: my first guess is a misconfiguration in your local X server, since that's getting the click events first.  can you connect to the linux box (eg, via VLC) and see the right-click working there?

Comment: Yes, right click works on Linux

Comment: are you starting Xming with the `-multiwindow` option?

Comment: The -multiwindow allowed me access to the right click and file menu, but only until I move the window.  Once the java application's window is moved, then there is no way to left or right click menu items on the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=62022&tstart=0) post on the java.net forums it seems that there are "incorrect insets detection when using the Xming".  The fix is to set the AWT_TOOLKIT environment variable.  Explanation for why can be found on Sun's page [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/awt/1.5/xawt.html).

```
AWT_TOOLKIT=MToolkit
```

Setting this environment variable fixed all problems.
Update:
The link containing the original link has changed. See [here](https://www.java.net/node/693520).

Comment: the quote from the forum is "incorrect insets detection when using the Xming", which doesn't necessarily imply it's Xming doing the incorrect detection.  sounds like it's a bug in Swing.  good job finding the workaround, +1!

Comment: Good point.  I'll correct my quote and reword to not put Xming at fault.

Comment: So, this seemed to solve the problem for a while for me too, however, I'm now faced with another problem, I sometimes get some sort of keyboard focus/event problem, I can't type in my textboxes and such until i change the focuse to another window and back... anyone run into this ?

Comment: @nathan The given link page not found. (https://www.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=62022&tstart=0) any alternate link?

Comment: @Sridhar I updated the link.

Answer (score 2):

I also had errors in our Solaris 11 server to Windows 7 desktop using Xming. We were installing some Oracle (Java) apps on the Solaris 11 server and we had issues with XMing with input field becoming uneditable at random times. We tried so many parameter changes and nothing worked (not even a corporate license of Exceed, but that was another issue). We tried using MobaXterm and that worked well and allowed us to do our Oracle installs without issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem with Xming and a remote Java application installer on CentOS 6.9. When I used Xlaunch and selected the "Multiple windows" mode and no access control - I was unable to click on text fields in the UI. The Xming command from the log was:

```
Xming :0 -multiwindow -clipboard -ac
```

However I just found that if I used "One window" mode then I was able to click on text fields and edit content :)

```
Xming :0 -clipboard -ac
```

I recommend you try this for the problem you faced (unless you have already switched over to mobaxterm). I am happy to have a workaround that works but still curious to know the root cause and if its possible to fix this for multiwindow mode. I did try AWT_TOOLKIT=MToolkit but this made no difference for me in multiwindow mode.

Comment: I found this resolved a similar issue for me as well, in which a remote java app displayed under `Xming :0 -multiwindow` would display in windows taskbar could not be alt-tabbed or otherwise brought to the foreground.  I found that `export AWT_TOOLKIT=MToolkit` (as suggested in http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/trouble.php) similarly did not resolve my issue. I too would really prefer to continue using -multiwindow and wonder if you (or others) might have found a workaround.

Comment: Also, `Xming -compositewm -multiwindow` _slightly_ improved windowing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this other XServer tool?

http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/

I used to have issues with XMing, this one is not only faster, but solved some of those issues for me (input field becoming uneditable among them).

I'm using the free 6.2 portable version. Make sure you start your session from inside the GUI, this way you don't even have to export the display.

I hope this helps!